# Deleting a mutated derived template class instance created by placement new

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

For a deserialization process I've written a base class which mutates into a derived one depending on the serialized data. To achieve this I'm using the placement new operator. Everything works fine until I try to delete the instance. I've tried different approaches but end up with a Heap corruption error every time. I've created a simplified example code showing my approaches.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010.

Here is the small sample code demonstrating the problem:

Header.h

```
#pragma once

#include <type_traits>

class BaseClass
{
private:
    int _someValue;

    BaseClass(const BaseClass &other); // remove copy constructor
    BaseClass(BaseClass &&other); // remove move constructor
    BaseClass &operator=(const BaseClass &other); // remove assignment operator

public:
    BaseClass(void);
    virtual ~BaseClass(void);

    void ChangeType(bool b);
};

template<typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
private:
    T _someMoreData;

    DerivedClass(const DerivedClass &other); // remove copy constructor
    DerivedClass(DerivedClass &&other); // remove move constructor
    DerivedClass &operator=(const DerivedClass &other); // remove assignment operator

public:
    DerivedClass(void) :
      _someMoreData(0)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value || std::is_same<T, long>::value, "DerivedClass must be used with 'int' or 'long'.");
    }

    virtual ~DerivedClass(void)
    {}
};
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "Header.h"

BaseClass::BaseClass() :
    _someValue(0)
{}

BaseClass::~BaseClass()
{}

void BaseClass::ChangeType(bool b)
{
    this->~BaseClass();
    if (b)
        new (this) DerivedClass<int>();
    else
        new (this) DerivedClass<long>();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BaseClass *pBC = new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass<int> *pDC = nullptr;

    pBC->ChangeType(true);
    pDC = reinterpret_cast<DerivedClass<int> *>(pBC);

    // work with pDC ...

    // 1st try:
    delete pBC; // ERROR: Heap Corruption

    // 2nd try:
    pBC->~BaseClass(); 
    ::operator delete(pBC); // ERROR: Heap Corruption

    // 3rd try:
    pDC->~DerivedClass();
    ::operator delete(pDC); // ERROR: Heap Corruption

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#111) at 0x004D6970.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

How am I supposed to delete these instances in a clean way?

Comment: The derived class is larger than the base, that placement new can't possibly be valid. Why are you trying to do that with inheritance?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! The reason for the exception is the difference in size of `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass`. After I changed the size of `DerivedClass` to fit the size of `BaseClass` everything works as expected.

I only use the placement new operator because it simplifies things in my code. Unfortunately it would be complicated to rewrite the exiting code to inheritance and factory methods.